# Win Server 2019 - XAMPP - MYSQL Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, root, access-denied

I've been browsing the web and this site from other users which have had this issue and reading the comments to resolve however I've not had much luck and i'm going bonkers trying to work out the issue.

I have two servers - Win Server 2019 and both use XAMPP with Apache and MYSQL, the first server (1) has been running for over a year perfectly fine, however I'm setting up another server (2) to use as a test environment but with a fresh install of windows, xampp along with the Apache/MYSQL modules.

I'm using Invision Community application but I'm getting this upon the first page of installation:
MySQL Requirements

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ips4.php:317 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ips4.php(317): mysqli->__construct('localhost') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ips4.php(340): my_mysqli->__construct('localhost') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ips4.php on line 317

IPS4.php is just a file to state whether the server meets all the requirements for the application.

I've then compared MYSQL on (1) to the install on (2) and I've matched the details, given privileges to "root" user on all of the available databases within PHPMYADMIN, granted full grants and then reloaded them, restarted MYSQL and Apache and still same issue.

Normally the Invision software continues through to then request the database details, user details etc. but it hasn't got to that point yet.

The only differences I can see between both servers is (1) is running PHP 7.3.7 | Apache 2.4.39 | MySQL 5.0.12 and server (2) is running PHP 8.2.0 | Apache 2.4.54 | MySQL 8.2.0

I was hoping I would just install XAMPP and then transfer the files to install the software and then configure it to choose which DB/User and then install and get started but apparently not.

ROOT doesn't have a password on (2) but does on (1), when I add a password to (2), I'm then unable to access PHPMYADMIN and doesn't ask for a password to log in. I've spent a few hours today trying to resolve this but now I think I'd like some advice. Many thanks

Setting root password, then flushing privileges, granting full permissions on all databases, copying the mysql files from server (1) to server (2). uninstalling XAMPP and reinstalling.

I don't recall ever needing to do anything for permissions when I setup this software on server (1). I've also installed this software on a few linux servers but didn't enjoy using linux so I stopped using it.

EDIT: It seems it's using MariaDB 10.4.27

Comment: I didn't do anything different with the first server, I don't see where I need to set a user this time round unless it's some addition in the newer versions. I'll uninstall XAMPP tomorrow and reinstall, it has a introduction in the htdocs folder which I deleted as I thought it was going to be the same setup as the previous server but apparently not, so it may go into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Set a password for root on (2).

Change the phpMyAdmin `config.inc.php` file,change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

then phpMyAdmin will throw a login dialog and ask for a user/password

That should sort out the phpMyAdmin issue.

> Big Note: You really should not be using the `root` account for any app/website access. Instead you should create a user account in MySQL/mariaDB one for each app/website that has access only to the database(s) required for that app/website. (Basic Security)

Comment: Thanks pal, I've made that amendment for PHPMYADMIN. I will be using a different username within MySQL, it's just all default at the moment as I just installed it on the server and just trying to get past this error :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a user called "Any" hostname "%" which looks to be what was causing the issue, I gave it access to all databases (most likely wrong thing to do but it's internally accessed only - no access outside of our network).

This got rid of the error

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes this was the wrong thing to do. Its better to actually delete that user